# What is the correct way to describe Oxygen and CO2?

Tags: grammar

I want to say that `Oxygen breaks down to CO2 (carbon dioxide)`. Is this the correct term?
Or, should I say "decomposes" or "breaks into"?

Comment: None of the above. Oxygen is a component of CO2 not the other way round, formed by 'oxidisation'… like rusty iron. It is an additive process not a subtractive one. You can split CO2 into CO & O2, but splitting it to C and O2 is difficult. You need a chemistry site not linguistics to adequately describe this in a way not confusing to other chemists.

Comment: I think this question is [on-topic](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for the [chemistry.se] site ("_Questions about nomenclature, standards, et cetera pertaining to chemistry._")